# Anaconda environments - python file not found?

Tags: python, macos, path, anaconda, environment

recently, after a computer crash, I have tried to set up my Anaconda and Pycharm.

I have gotten anaconda to work both in python 2.7 and 3.6 environments and it is only when running a specific .py file, that I get the following error:

```
Error running 'eigenfaces': Error running  "/anaconda3/envs/Py2.7/bin/python" (in directory "/Users/luka/Dropbox/Luka/Data Analysis/Data Science Nanodegree/P5/ud120-projects-master/pca"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

I went to inspect the directory, mentioned by the error : "/anaconda3/envs/Py2.7/bin/python" and as you can see from the below picture, the actualy python file is white.
[image]

Instead, as you can see in the picture, the executable file "python2.7" is black, as expected. Would you be so kind and check in your envs folder, if you have the same situation (python file in white, seems like a short cut / alias...)?

I would assume that somehow I am referencing the wrong file. How can I switch the reference to my "python2.7" executable file?

Edit:
I just checked how where the white shortcut leads, and it is linked to the black exe file, python2.7, so this works. For testing purposes, I have renamed the python file itself and deleted the shortcut, but the problem remains, when I re-run the .py file.

Thank you very much for your help.